# Android generalized kotlin function to return any class and take any parameter

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

In my network repository, I have already a generalized function like this that will work when my API returns a particular model -

```
override suspend fun getRandomSchoolImageFromRemote(): SchoolResult {
    return generalizedFunction {
        remoteInterface.getRandomImage()
    } 
}

override suspend fun getSchoolImageByIdFromRemote(id: String): SchoolResult {
    return generalizedFunction {
        remoteInterface.getSchoolImageById(id)
    }
}
```

And my generalized function looks like this -

```
private inline fun generalizedFunction(block: () -> SchoolModel): SchoolResult {
    if (util.checkDeviceInternet()) {
        try {
            val result = block()
            if (result.status == "200") {
                return SchoolResult.Content(result)
            } else {
                return SchoolResult.Error(SchoolResult.ErrorType.API_ERROR)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return SchoolResult.Error(SchoolResult.ErrorType.API_ERROR)
        }
    } else {
        return SchoolResult.Error(SchoolResult.ErrorType.NO_INTERNET)
    }
}
```

Currently my genjeralized function can return a sealed class `SchoolResult` and also can only take `SchoolModel` as parameter. However I want to have this generalized function even more generalized where it can handle any model as parameter such as `ChildrenModel` or event just a `Unit` and can return any Sealed class such as `SchoolResult` or `ChildrenResult`. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down the question into to problems:

1. You want to have a generic input type
2. You want to have a generic output type with a constraint on it being a sealed class.

We can use generics to solve both problems which allows us to provide arguments and output type as a parameter.

For example, to solve the first problem, we can use something like this

```
private inline fun <INPUT> generalizedFunction(block: () -> INPUT): SchoolResult {
    ...
}
```

but this means that you don't have direct access to `.status` which you use to do `result.status == "200"`. So you will need to either re-think your models or your logic inside the function to overcome this.

The second problem is quite tricky. Say we did something like this

```
private inline fun <INPUT, OUTPUT> generalizedFunction(block: () -> INPUT): OUTPUT {
    ...
}
```

There is no way for us to know if `OUTPUT` is a sealed class or not and even if it is a sealed class, there is no way to know its children such as `Content` and `Error`.

One way to go about this is to wrap your result in a more generic way. So you can do something like this for example:

```
sealed class Result<out T> {
    data class Content<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
    data class Error<out T>(val errorCode: ErrorType) : Result<T>()
}
```

then the final outcome for a truly general method would be

```
private inline fun <INPUT,OUTPUT> generalizedFunction(block: () -> INPUT): Result<OUTPUT> {
    if (util.checkDeviceInternet()) {
        try {
            val result = block()
            if (result.status == "200") {
                return Result.Content(result)
            } else {
                return Result.Error(ErrorType.API_ERROR)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return Result.Error(ErrorType.API_ERROR)
        }
    } else {
        return Result.Error(ErrorType.NO_INTERNET)
    }
}
```

where `ErrorType` is a more generic enum that's not part of `SchoolResult`.